# Hide View cell in ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview grouped, and everytime i touch the group header, all the items in the group hide, but for some reason the cells remain

I have tried to set a binded IsVisible property to all elements in the ViewCell, but still cant make it work

Heres my ListView xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="GroupsList"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Dishes}"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                      SeparatorColor="Black"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Height="50">
                            <StackLayout
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                BackgroundColor="LightSlateGray">
                                <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        BorderColor="Transparent"
                                        BorderWidth="0"
                                        Text="{Binding Key}"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectGroupHeader, Source={x:Reference DishesPage}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Key}"
                                        ContentLayout="Right, 300"
                                        ImageSource="next_disclosure"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView Padding="2, 5, 5, 0"
                                         IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
                                <Frame Padding="2"
                                       HasShadow="False"
                                       BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Margin="10"
                                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               TextColor="Black"
                                               FontSize="Medium"
                                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here is my ViewModel code:

```
private async Task SelectedGroupHeader(string item)
        {
            foreach(var group in Dishes)
            {
                if(item == group.Key)
                {
                    foreach(var dish in group)
                    {
                        if (dish.IsVisible)
                        {
                            dish.IsVisible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dish.IsVisible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

before hiding:
[image]

after hiding
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `ContentView.IsVisible` to `false` when you want to hide the **items**, but when you do that you hide the `ContentView` and the **items** remain in the list, so you still see the items, but without a `ContentView` (blanks)!

One way i found out you can achieve your purpose is to store somewhere the **items** of the tapped group and clear its content when you tap on it. When you do that the group becomes empty, and thus the items in the `ListView` are not visible anymore. When you tap again in the group header you add again the **items** to the group so that the `ListView` displays again your items.

The code i got working is more or less as follows:

In **XAML** i only removed the binding to `ContentView.IsVisible`:

```
<ListView x:Name="GroupsList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Dishes}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                  SeparatorColor="Black"
                  SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="50">
                        <StackLayout
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="LightSlateGray">
                            <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    BorderColor="Transparent"
                                    BorderWidth="0"
                                    Text="{Binding Key}"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectGroupHeader, Source={x:Reference DishesPage}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Key}"
                                    ContentLayout="Right, 300"
                                    ImageSource="next_disclosure"></Button>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView Padding="2, 5, 5, 0">
                            <Frame Padding="2"
                                   HasShadow="False"
                                   BackgroundColor="White">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Margin="10"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           FontSize="Medium"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In your **ViewModel** you would have to do something like:

```
private async Task SelectedGroupHeader(string item)
    {
        foreach(var group in Dishes)
        {
            if(item == group.Key)
            {
                if(!group.IsHidden)
                {
                    group.Clear();
                    group.IsHidden = true; // This is simply a flag you can set in your group class to keep track of if the group is collapsed or not
                }
                else
                {
                    AddItemsToGroup(group)// Add this group all the elements that belongs to it.

                    group.IsHidden = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Note: this only works if your collection of items is an `ObservableCollection`, so that the `ListView` gets notified when the collection changes!